# Passing indexed list elements as key values for a dictionary in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I am new to *python*, and am trying to make use of `string.format()` to pass indexed elements of a list as the key values for my dictionary. This will then be used in a `request`.

To be more specific, the overarching idea for this is that the input for the list will be chosen/spoken by the client. This list, which will vary with spoken utterance, will then have it's elements passed to fill parameters for a `request.get`. This gets information that it will then send to a database, so it needs to be flexible; this is why I do not want the passed string elements to be explicitly specified, and would rather use their indexed placements in the list. I include this because there might be a way other than with `requests` that I could do this, but I'm just not sure how. Here is what my code looks like:

```
import requests

def func():
    # query will be populated via spoken utterances; for now it's hard-coded for testing purposes
    query = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
    intent = {'string1': '{0[0]}', 'string2': '{0[1]}', 'RelString': '{0[2]}'}.format(query)
    url = "http://path-to-cloudobject"
    r = requests.get(url, params=intent)
    return r.text
```

Because I know where the issue lies, I've tried inputting `print(intent)` underneath `intent` to get a look at what's going on but that doesn't help; I get nothing upon execution. Is there an easier (and legal) way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Your `intent` is a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) which doesn't have a [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#format) method. What you want to do instead, is format every value in that dictionary to map to the right query field. Try this instead:

```
>>> query = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
>>> intent = {'string1': '{0}'.format(query[0]), 'string2': '{0}'.format(query[1]), 'RelString': '{0}'.format(query[2])}
>>> intent
{'RelString': 'value3', 'string2': 'value2', 'string1': 'value1'}
>>>
```

As a matter of fact this could be further simplified with [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> query = ['value1', 'value2', 'value3']
>>> intent = dict(zip(['string1', 'string2', 'RelString'], query))
>>> intent
{'RelString': 'value3', 'string2': 'value2', 'string1': 'value1'}
>>>
```

Where the order of keys `['string1', 'string2', 'RelString']` must correspond to the order of values inside `query`.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense than what I was doing, and I really like the added use of `zip` to make it cleaner (which helps me, as I always order keys in the way I'm mapping them to values anyway)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly . The following should be the desired output value for "intent" after formatting:

```
{'string1': 'value1[0]', 'string2': 'value2[1]', 'RelString':    'value3[2]'}
```

You can actually convert dictionary into string  and then back to Dictionary through tuples as

```
import ast
query = ["value1", "value2", "value3"]
intent = {'string1': '{0}[0]', 'string2': '{1}[1]', 'RelString': '{2}[2]'}
tupleIntent = intent.items()
listIntent = ast.literal_eval(str(tupleIntent).format(*query))
DictIntent = dict(listIntent)
print DictIntent
```

I did edit your "intent" dictionary to match the formatting results.